# Display Image in Proper Orientation - Blazor Server Side

Tags: javascript, html, css, blazor, blazor-server-side

My page is displaying files from azure storage, some of which are in a landscape orientation while others are in portrait. My issue is that all of the files are displaying as landscape. At first I simply tried to add the following css:

```
.photo{
    image-orientation: from-image;
}
```

But it seems like that css is deprecated/doesn't work on edge and chrome.

Next I tried to use blueimp's [JavaScript-Load-Image](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image). Which is working to show the image, but the orientation isn't changing - they are all still showing in landscape.

JavaScript:

```
function RotateImage(fileURL) {
    var loadingImage = loadImage(
        fileURL,
        function (img) {
            document.body.appendChild(img)
        },
        { orientation: true }
    )

    return loadingImage;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="photosGridDiv">
    @foreach (var file in currentFiles)
    {
        <div>
            @(JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("RotateImage", file.filePath))
            <br />
            <a href="@file.filePath">@file.fileName</a>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

How the images look now (the first and second should be portrait):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe handle rotation on client side, using exif-js(https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) and apply a CSS transform.

```
EXIF.getData(imageElement, function() {
    var orientation = EXIF.getTag(this, "Orientation");
    if(orientation == 6)
        $(imageElement).css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)')
});
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: orientation is not defined"

Comment: @SaraCox Can you check if the image has orientation info available in the Exif?

Comment: I believe so, if I am looking at this right. If I right click the file and go to properties under the details tab there is an EXIF version property with a value of 0231